# NumericValueOutOfRange error for text column when importing data from S3 into RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, psycopg2

I'm currently uploading a .csv file from an S3 bucket to a Postgres RDS table. I'm using the aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 function. When I execute the function I get an error telling me that "NumericValueOutOfRange: value "7343154608" is out of range for type integer. CONTEXT:  COPY test, line 2, column id: "7343154608"".

7343154608 is the first value in the .csv file, under the column Company_Phone_Number which is of the data type text. I don't understand when copying the data from S3 to Postgres RDS it is thinking that the value is out of range for type integer, when the column is type text.

**Create Table Command:**
CREATE TABLE test(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
Company_Phone_Number TEXT,
Created_Date DATE,
Violation_Date DATE)

**DB Schema:**

| table_name | column_name | data_type | table_schema |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test | id | integer | public |
| test | company_phone_number | text | public |
| test | created_date | date | public |
| test | violation_date | date | public |

[Information_Schema.Columns for the table from psql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j3uF.png)

[SQL Command and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpZDl.png)

Comment: 7343154608 is > than the MAX integer value

Comment: @Emanuele The company_phone_number column is of the data type text not integer, so there shouldn't be any max int error, which is why I'm confused.

Comment: That in not a Postgres error message. The corresponding Postgres error would be  *SQL Error [22003]: ERROR: integer out of range*. I would suspect it is from the  AWS function.  Possibility: Check your CSV, Is the company_phone_number quoted. If not try try just a line or 2 and quote that field. If that works check the Excel see how the column is defined there. Perhaps recreate the CSV.